# how to add elements of data frame with their respective unique columns

Tags: r

[image]

I have data like this, in a data frame. Here 1 and 3 refer to name of states, which are unique. how do i add up values below them? I mean, in the image shown, my output should be 1 and 1500 and 3 and 500. basically add up values below 1 and consolidate it under 1 and add up values below 3 and sum it up under 3. i want to add the respective terms and unable to do it. any resource or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It feels like your data.frame would make more sense if you transposed it, i.e. it has two columns and many rows. This would make aggregating and performing other manipulations easier to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
df = data.frame(A=c(1,500),B=c(3,300),C=c(3,200),D=c(1,500),E=c(1,500))
tapply(as.numeric(df[2,]),as.factor(df[1,]), sum)
```

Output:

```
   1    3 
1500  500
```